# How do I build a portfolio?

Tags: skills

After graduating, I started self-teaching myself SQL using Codecademy and books. I've listed this on my resume in a way that implies I'm not very experienced with the language but am familiar with it. I'd like a way to show employers my SQL skills more directly.

Standard advice to show employers your skills is to create projects or portfolios. Here's where my problem lies: I have *no* idea what the format is for these. Considering that I'm dealing SQL, I can't just build a website or app to show what I know. I'm assuming that projects in a portfolio involve more than just a document of plain code. Or is that all there is to it?

Comment: Given that SQL is more of a supporting back-end technology for broader applications, it's a bit difficult to show specific 'portfolio' type examples of SQL usage. You might then want to start looking more into overall structures and patterns of how database systems are setup, right from a small personal website to a large enterprise web-application. Understanding these design decisions and what makes sense in what context is more in-line with what you would want to show employers I think.

Comment: Github is a excellent way to create a portfolio of your code. You can easily share it too and *almost* everyone knows what github is.

Comment: I would also recommend joining and participlating in the StackOverflow and Database Administrator SE sites.  Both have tons of questions regarding how to query for this or that.  Most specify the RDBMS they are related to and it is very easy to show a profile of questions you have successfully answered.

Comment: Can you explain why you *want* to build a portfolio? What is wrong with getting a job with your college education?

Comment: I'm with @nvoigt on this. The *actual* standard advice to demonstrate skills is to have a work history where you *used* those skills. Very few people or industries care about a portfolio, especially IT. It's useful for candidates without work experience but even there the portfolio is more of a way to discuss programming when you can't based the conversation on work experience.

Comment: @nvoigt There's plenty of companies that are looking to hire the best.  Even straight out of undergrad, they want to see actual projects.  Maybe they don't have a tech background.  OP doesn't need to explain why to you.

Comment: @Lilienthal OP doesn't have work experience, and as you said, in that circumstance a portfolio is helpful.  You are also wrong about portfolios in IT.  For example, anyone hiring a data scientist will want to see actual projects.

Comment: @Hobbes Sure the OP does not need to explain *anything*. But I cannot answer his question if I don't know why he needs a portfolio on top of a college education, so I asked. An answer might look totally different between the extremes of "I want to impress Google with extra knowledge" and "My college degree was in history of art and I'm looking to go into CS now".

Comment: @Hobbes Helpful in some cases. There are cases like the example you give but then the portfolio grows naturally alongside experience. OP gives no indication whether he has internship experience, what his degree is in or how new he is to the skills he wants a portfolio for (SQL). Really, the question as asked is probably off-topic unless we broaden it to "what does a programming portfolio look like?". Even then we'd need to establish some baseline purpose for such a portfolio.

Comment: @Lilienthal  The point is you made an incorrect claim regarding portfolios in IT and then contradicted yourself.  The question is fine and others have given good responses.

Comment: @Hobbes Eh no. So far we only have different opinions on the value of portfolios in IT and I never contradicted myself. But this is rapidly going off-topic so join me in [chat] if you want to argue the point. As for the question, it isn't fine, which is why it's getting close votes. The fact that they're three different types is a good indicator that the question has problems.

Comment: @nvoigt I have a degree in science, and like I said, I'm self-teaching myself these new skills. I have no background in programming. "What is wrong with getting a job with your college education?" Because learning skills relevant to what I want to get into makes me more marketable (hopefully). I'm a bit frustrated with all the experienced adults expecting a college degree to be enough to get a good job nowadays. Of course, experience is ideal, but I can't get any if no one hires me. Hence, self-taught skills.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a project on github or bitbucket, and use SQL in that project. You can show a couple of demos, maybe a test suite for some back-end feature, or another project that makes use of SQL. This doesn't have to have a particular goal, but should have a "narrative" about what you're trying to do or show. Anyone can cut-and-paste code from elsewhere, so you need to show that you have a logical progression of ideas, and therefore couldn't have done that.

Both are free for this use case. It will only cost you time.

Answer (score 2):

In the past I have had job applications where they wanted to see SQL Code.  What they want to see is how you can utilize the data in the database.  The Microsoft sample databases are a great tool for this.

Start out and create a business question based on the sample database.  "How many of X or Y were sold on such and such a date to which buyers."  Follow that up with the SQL code for how you would determine the answer to the business question.  Get creative, think of the most complex questions or caculations that could be made of the data in the sample database, and write SQL to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

I think in expounding on technical subjects where there's no front-end, you need to show:

1. Problem domain
2. Business rules
3. Technical approach (EXACTLY how the implementation should work and why it's a good one.  Enumerate some possible alternatives and explain why you didn't use them.)
4. Solution

If you can cover the first three, the last is less relevant.